# Series expansion of expressions with Log and PolyLog functions

Tags: bugs, special-functions, series-expansion

The following code

```
Series[Log[1 - zz] Log[2 zz^3] - PolyLog[2, 1/zz], {zz, 0, 0}, 
 Assumptions -> zz > 0]
% // Normal
```

returns

```
(log^2(zz)/2-I \[Pi] log(zz)-\[Pi]^2/3)+O(zz^1)

log^2(zz)/2-I \[Pi] log(zz)-\[Pi]^2/3
```

on Mathematica versions 8, 9, 10.3, 11.0 and 11.1. So I assume that intrinsically Mathematica has no issues with this expansion. For some reason version 11.2 not only gives me one order more than I requested, but also returns an expression with an infinity

```
(-zz+O(zz^2)) log(O(zz^3))+((log^2(zz)/2-I \[Pi] log(zz)-\[Pi]^2/3)+zz+O(zz^2))

zz \[Infinity]+zz+log^2(zz)/2-I \[Pi] log(zz)-\[Pi]^2/3
```

I would say at least that this behavior is inconsistent with the output of the previous versions. Is it a bug or is there something I'm missing about `Series` in version 11.2?

Comment: Not yet a definitive answer, but i suspect it is a bug. Will investigate tomorrow or so.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Notice that `SeriesCoefficient[
 Log[1 - zz] Log[2 zz^3] - PolyLog[2, 1/zz], {zz, 0, 0}, 
 Assumptions -> zz > 0]` does not evaluate on version 11.2 but works fine with 11.1, 10.3 and so on.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Any news on this issue?

Comment: It's an issue with handling of empty coefficient lists in `SeriesData` objects. Will be testing a possible fix, not yet sure what the outcome will be.

Comment: Since this got bumped to the homepage, I added the 'bugs' tag.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Could you please also have a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162257/series-expansion-of-expressions-with-log-and-polylog-functions-again?noredirect=1#comment430553_162257? Is this related to this bug, or is it something that requires a different fix.

Comment: Here Mathematica 11.3 (again) returns the correct result. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) as follows:

```
Assuming[
    zz>0,
    Log[1-zz] Log[2 zz^3] - PolyLog[2, 1/zz] /. zz->zz+O[zz]^3
] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(\frac{\log ^2(\operatorname{zz})}{2}-i \pi  \log (\operatorname{zz})-\frac{\pi
>    ^2}{3}\right)+O\left(\operatorname{zz}^1\right)$

Answer (score 0):

You take too small order in `{zz, 0, 0}`. The following works well in version 11.2.

```
Series[Log[1 - zz] Log[2 zz^3] - PolyLog[2, 1/zz], {zz, 0, 4}, Assumptions -> zz > 0]
```

> $$\left(\frac{\log ^2(\text{zz})}{2}-i \pi  \log (\text{zz})-\frac{\pi ^2}{3}\right)+\text{zz} (-3 \log (\text{zz})+1-\log (2))+\frac{1}{4} \text{zz}^2 (-6 \log (\text{zz})+1-2 \log (2))+\text{zz}^3 \left(-\log (\text{zz})+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{\log (2)}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{16} \text{zz}^4 (-12 \log (\text{zz})+1-4 \log (2))+O\left(\text{zz}^5\right)  $$

```
% // Normal
```

> $$ \frac{1}{16} \text{zz}^4 (-12 \log (\text{zz})+1-4 \log (2))+\text{zz}^3 \left(-\log (\text{zz})+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{\log (2)}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \text{zz}^2 (-6 \log (\text{zz})+1-2 \log (2))+\frac{\log ^2(\text{zz})}{2}+\text{zz} (-3 \log (\text{zz})+1-\log (2))-i \pi  \log (\text{zz})+\frac{\pi ^2}{3} $$

The order can be decreased to 3 from 4, but no to 2.

Addition. The above shows the answer

```
(log^2(zz)/2-I \[Pi] log(zz)-\[Pi]^2/3)+O(zz^1)
```

in some previous versions is not correct because $x\log x \neq O(x),\, x \to 0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not quite understand your answer. The point of looking at the 0th order is to extract the leading order behavior of the function around the expansion point. I'm really not interested in higher orders here. If you look at `ex1 = SeriesCoefficient[
  Log[1 - zz] Log[2 zz^3] - PolyLog[2, 1/zz], {zz, 0, 0}, 
  Assumptions -> zz > 0]`, 
`ex2 = SeriesCoefficient[
  Log[1 - zz] Log[2 zz^3] - PolyLog[2, 1/zz], {zz, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> zz > 0]` and `Plot[{Re[ex1], zz Re[ex2]}, {zz, -1, 1}]` in version 11.0 or any older version, then it is clear that

Comment: the largest contribution around `zz=0` comes from the
logs, not logs times zz. And this is exactly what I want
to know. So in my view the result given
by all the previous versions of Mathematica is correct.
A simpler example which shares the same features would be
`Normal[Series[(a Log[x] + b Log[x]^2) Sqrt[1 + x], {x, 0, 0}]]`
Here the 0th order expansion correctly returns only the logs
both on Mathematica 11.2 and older versions.

Comment: @vsht: The expansion (log^2(zz)/2-I \[Pi] log(zz)-\[Pi]^2/3)+O(zz^1) is incorrect because of O(zz^1).  It should be (log^2(zz)/2-I \[Pi] log(zz)-\[Pi]^2/3)+O(zz^1*log(zz)).Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: AFAIK it is a notation convention of Mathematica to show only the expansion parameter in the Landau symbol. You may not like it for various reasons, but this is how it works across many versions. Moreover, this behavior is not limited to my example. `Normal[Series[(a Log[x] + b Log[x]^2) Sqrt[1 + x], {x, 0, 0}]]` behaves in exactly the same way. Anyway, my original question was about `Series` returning naked singularities and more orders than requested, not about the big O notation. So I still fail to see how your answer is related to the original question.

Comment: @vsht: I submitted that bug in Series.