# Series expansion of expressions with Log and PolyLog functions (again)

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I think that I discovered another (c.f. [Series expansion of expressions with Log and PolyLog functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159777/series-expansion-of-expressions-with-log-and-polylog-functions)) issue related to `Series` and `PolyLog`.

Consider the following expression

```
exp = (-16*Pi^2*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]])/3 + (16*Pi^2*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]])/
   x^4 + (16*Pi^2*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]])/(3*x^2) + (32*Pi^2*
     Log[1 + Sqrt[x]])/(3*x) + (32*Pi^2*x*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]])/
   3 - (16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^3)/3 + (16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^3)/
   x^4 + (16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^3)/(3*x^2) + (32*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^3)/(3*
     x) + (32*x*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^3)/3 + (16*Pi^2*Log[1 - x])/
   3 - (16*Pi^2*Log[1 - x])/
   x^4 - (16*Pi^2*Log[1 - x])/(3*x^2) - (32*Pi^2*Log[1 - x])/(3*
     x) - (32*Pi^2*x*Log[1 - x])/3 + 
  16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*
   Log[1 - x] - (48*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[1 - x])/
   x^4 - (16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[1 - x])/
   x^2 - (32*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[1 - x])/x - 
  32*x*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[1 - x] - 
  16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*
   Log[1 - x]^2 + (48*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]^2)/
   x^4 + (16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]^2)/
   x^2 + (32*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]^2)/x + 
  32*x*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]^2 + (16*Log[1 - x]^3)/
   3 - (16*Log[1 - x]^3)/
   x^4 - (16*Log[1 - x]^3)/(3*x^2) - (32*Log[1 - x]^3)/(3*x) - (32*x*
     Log[1 - x]^3)/3 - 
  8*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[x] + (24*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[x])/
   x^4 + (8*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[x])/
   x^2 + (16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[x])/x + 
  16*x*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]^2*Log[x] + 
  16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]*
   Log[x] - (48*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]*Log[x])/
   x^4 - (16*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]*Log[x])/
   x^2 - (32*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]*Log[x])/x - 
  32*x*Log[1 + Sqrt[x]]*Log[1 - x]*Log[x] - 
  8*Log[1 - x]^2*Log[x] + (24*Log[1 - x]^2*Log[x])/
   x^4 + (8*Log[1 - x]^2*Log[x])/x^2 + (16*Log[1 - x]^2*Log[x])/x + 
  16*x*Log[1 - x]^2*Log[x] - 
  32*PolyLog[3, 1 - Sqrt[x]] + (96*PolyLog[3, 1 - Sqrt[x]])/
   x^4 + (32*PolyLog[3, 1 - Sqrt[x]])/
   x^2 + (64*PolyLog[3, 1 - Sqrt[x]])/x + 
  64*x*PolyLog[3, 1 - Sqrt[x]] - 
  32*PolyLog[3, Sqrt[x]] + (96*PolyLog[3, Sqrt[x]])/
   x^4 + (32*PolyLog[3, Sqrt[x]])/x^2 + (64*PolyLog[3, Sqrt[x]])/x + 
  64*x*PolyLog[3, Sqrt[x]] - 
  32*PolyLog[
    3, -(Sqrt[x]/(1 - Sqrt[x]))] + (96*
     PolyLog[3, -(Sqrt[x]/(1 - Sqrt[x]))])/
   x^4 + (32*PolyLog[3, -(Sqrt[x]/(1 - Sqrt[x]))])/
   x^2 + (64*PolyLog[3, -(Sqrt[x]/(1 - Sqrt[x]))])/x + 
  64*x*PolyLog[3, -(Sqrt[x]/(1 - Sqrt[x]))] + 
  32*Zeta[3] - (96*Zeta[3])/x^4 - (32*Zeta[3])/x^2 - (64*Zeta[3])/x - 
  64*x*Zeta[3]
```

`exp` can be made much shorter by applying `Simplify` to it, but in my case it is a part of a much larger expression and applying `Simplify` to the whole expression makes little sense.

In fact, for `x` between `0` and `1` `exp` vanishes identically. Therefore, if I expand this expression in `x` around `0` the expected result is zero. With Mathematica 8 and Mathematica 9 I get the desired result so that

```
Series[exp, {x, 0, 0}] // Normal
```

yields

```
0
```

However, starting with Mathematica 10 (I have version 10.3 here) something strange is going on. For some reason

```
Series[exp, {x, 0, 0}] // Normal
```

returns

```
-3201281/105840 + 2*Pi^2 + (84*(-3 + Log[x]))/(5*Sqrt[x]) + (1089*Log[x])/70
```

but

```
Series[Simplify[exp], {x, 0, 0}] // Normal
```

still gives me the correct result. The same behavior is observed with Mathematica 11.0 and 11.2. Using `Assumptions -> x > 0` or `Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1` does not change anything.

To me this very much looks like a bug. In any case I believe that the result returned by `Series` should not depend on whether one have applied `Simplify` to the initial expression or not. However, as this behavior might also be caused by a misunderstanding from my side, I'd like to hear the opinion of other users from this site first.

Comment: These: `Series[exp[[48]], {x, 0, 0}]`, `Series[exp[[53]], {x, 0, 0}]`, `Series[exp[[58]], {x, 0, 0}]` return incorrect results unless sufficiently high order is calculated.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Is this issue related to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159777/series-expansion-of-expressions-with-log-and-polylog-functions?

Comment: Hard to be certain but it could be the same, or similar, underlying issues.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Seems like this is now fixed in Mathematica 11.3. Thanks a lot!