# Issues with the series expansion of Nielsen generalized polylogarithms in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: bugs, special-functions, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 11.3. Fixed in 12.0.**

---

In Mathematica 9, 10.3 and 11.0 I can easily expand `PolyLog[2, 2, x]` around
$x=1$ using

```
Series[PolyLog[2, 2, x], {x, 1, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 1]
```

to obtain

```
SeriesData[x, 1, {Pi^4/360}, 0, 1, 1]
```

In Mathematica 11.3 this works as well. Now if I put a minus sign in front of the `PolyLog`,

```
Series[-PolyLog[2, 2, x], {x, 1, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 1]
```

Mathematica 9, 10.3 and 11.0 of course still can do the expansion, but not Mathematica 11.3:

[image]

IMHO this looks like another bug in the expansion of special functions in the version 11.x. Or am I missing something here?

EDIT: In the meantime I discovered another glitch related to `PolyLog[2, 2, x]`. Consider

```
exp1 = (x PolyLog[4, x])/(1 - x)
exp2 = (x PolyLog[2, 2, x])/(1 - x)
```

Now doing

```
Series[exp1, {x, 1, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 1]
Series[exp2, {x, 1, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 1]
```

works fine in Mathematica versions 9 till 11.0

```
SeriesData[x, 1, {-Pi^4/90, -Pi^4/90 - Zeta[3]}, -1, 1, 1]
SeriesData[x, 1, {-Pi^4/360, -Pi^4/360 - Zeta[3]}, -1, 1, 1]
```

In Mathematica 11.3 the expansion of `exp2` doesn't work

[image]

Likewise, the expansion of `exp1+exp2` will result into errors. And this is where it gets interesting. For some reason even older Mathematica versions seem to have massive problems with the expansion of `exp1+exp2`, while they are perfectly capable to expand `exp1` and `exp2` separately. Just try to evaluate

```
Series[exp1+exp2, {x, 1, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 1]
```

with any Mathematica version you have in your disposal:

[image: Mathematica 8]
[image: Mathematica 9]
[image: Mathematica 10.3]
[image: Mathematica 11.0]

I find this somewhat surprising, since so far every time Mathematica 11.x returned a wrong expansion of such special functions, I could recover the correct result with Mathematica 8 or 9. However, this bug seems to affect all Mathematica versions starting at least with the version 8.

Comment: I agree it looks like a bug, and seems somehow familiar. I am away from the office this week, will check the status when I get back to see if it has been fixed.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for the quick reply. In the meantime I believe that I have discovered another issue with `Series` and `PolyLog[2,2,x]` which, however, affects all Mathematica versions, not just 11.3. It is in the edited version of this question. Perhaps you could have a look at this as well.

Comment: @vsht  The sum in your edited example works well after applying `Simplify ` or `Together ` in Version 8.0, but not without.  `Series[exp1 + exp2 // Simplify, {x, 1, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 1] ` yields  `SeriesData[x, 1, {
 Rational[-1, 72] Pi^4, Rational[-1, 72] Pi^4 - 2 Zeta[3]}, -1, 1, 1] ` .

Comment: @Akku14 This actually reminds me of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162257/series-expansion-of-expressions-with-log-and-polylog-functions-again?rq=1 My reasoning is the same as there: The real expressions are usually too complicated to throw a `Simplify` (or even `Together`) at them.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Any news on this issue?

Comment: Still an open problem, hoping to give it some attention when time permits.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks, I can confirm that these issues have been fixed in Mathematica 12.0 :)